# Plot of NSolve isn't displayed

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Suppose the function

```
v[x_, mp_, EN_] = x*EN/(mp + x*EN);
gamma[x_, mp_, EN_] = 1/Sqrt[1 - v[x, mp, EN]^2];
ECM[x_, mp_, EN_] = 
 x*EN*(1 - v[x, mp, EN])*gamma[x, mp, EN] + 
  Sqrt[mp^2 + (x*EN*(1 - v[x, mp, EN])*gamma[x, mp, EN])^2]
```

I want to plot the solution of the equation

```
m + 0.1 - ECM[x, 0.938, 3.6*10^4] + 0.938 == 0
```

for the range {m,0,7}:

```
Plot[NSolve[m + 0.1 - ECM[x, 0.938, 3.6*10^4] + 0.938 == 0, x, 
  Reals], {m, 0, 7}]
```

But the output is empty plot. What is the reason for this?

P.S. It seems that the equation has unique solution for each fixed m in the interval, so it seems that the problem isn't in this.

Comment: Look at the output of `NSolve` and look at its form. You have to extract the solutions using `x /. NSolve[ ... ]`. There will be examples in the documentation for `NSolve`, which you can get to by highlighting `NSolve` and hitting F1.

Answer (score 0):

```
v[x_, mp_, EN_] := x*EN/(mp + x*EN)

gamma[x_, mp_, EN_] := 1/Sqrt[1 - v[x, mp, EN]^2]

ECM[x_, mp_, EN_] := 
 x*EN*(1 - v[x, mp, EN])*gamma[x, mp, EN] + 
  Sqrt[mp^2 + (x*EN*(1 - v[x, mp, EN])*gamma[x, mp, EN])^2]
```

With

```
sol = 
 x /. First @ NSolve[m + 0.1 - ECM[x, 0.938, 3.6*10^4] + 0.938 == 0, x, Reals]
```

You get a long `ConditionalExpression` which tells you that `m` is defined within a range of `-1.038 < m < -0.1`.

You can plot it with

```
Plot[Evaluate @ sol[[1]], {m, -0.098, -1.038}]
```

[image]